# Poland : work permit application by employer

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, poland

This is my first question here, don't know if it is off-topic and belongs to travel exchange.

After applying everywhere for jobs and countless rejections, I hit some luck and was picked up by a company in Poland. All the interview steps went good and they selected me. Now, I am an Indian citizen and the company has started to apply for my work permit. I am wondering:

1. Are work permits for Indian citizens granted at all by Poland? I mean is it problematic for the company to obtain a work permit for a non-EU citizen?

Comment: @DipenShah Um, because I don't know? Neither do I know someone who has any similar experience. Problematic because wouldn't they have to justify why are they hiring a person from a non-EU country, when they have things like a database of unemployed people in the local market?

Comment: The company won't interview you if they would think there could be a problem obtaining a work permit. It should be a non-issue, however there's no 100% guarantee. If it's a technical job, you should not worry at all.